# Angular Material Stepper Oninit for all steps called on Step1 itself

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I have a Stepper with 3 steps each has it's own component. I am not using Forms at each step so i have bunch of input fields at every step.

The problem is Oninit method of all steps are called at load of first step itself. This messes up my code as i load data from a variable passed from Ist step to 2nd step.  Is there a way to avoid loading all oninit of every step on the first step itself?

See the problem on below link and open console: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpoj5j

I cannot find a solution though i found someone else also encountered the same.
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7985

Comment: could u create only one form an put all steps in that? just a suggestion.

Comment: did you try active step with conditionally load step component. so it won't get initialized.

Comment: @changulpaye - Can you provide an example ? I could not stop ngOnInit for all steps to be called as soon as the parent component is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the #stepper selectedIndex property to show the component and trigger the ngOnInit event.